# What is Sahaja Pranayam?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, sadhana, consciousness, yoga-sutras

It is said that even though there are many varieties of pranayam, the natural pranayam which one gets from birth i.e. Sahaja Pranayam is the best. This Pranayam was given by Lord Sri Krishna to his dearest disciple Arjuna.

My question: Are there any references about it in Gita? Any other scriptures that give more information about it?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/what-is-the-esoteric-meaning-of-bg-4-29/23292#23292